# search data in three tables in mysql server

Tags: mysql

Our requirement is making to search by name in three table which are

1. product_phone
2. product_tablet
3. Product_accessories

First table containing columns(Id,model_name)

Second table containing columns(Id,model_name)

Third table containing columns(Id,model_name).

So my requirement is to search by magnified glass by `model_name` these three table without using join.
I don't have any combination of each table.

Comment: please do some research before asking a question here.

Comment: when i am not using join then??????

Comment: Before give negative marks Please understand what is requirement of user.........lol

Comment: You should work on the code yourself firs try something and then ask a doubt here by presenting your work... anyways welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able to run a select query across multiple tables you just build a query that references all the tables .

```
select product_phone.name, product_tablet.name, product_accessories.name from product_phone, product_tablet, product_accessories
```

Be careful that your tables are not to big as to overwhelm your code with data , its a good idea to add a LIMIT clause to the end of your query to
give you the specific number of results.

LIMIT clauses - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

As your id fields appear to be unrelated you should not attempt to use
a join.  If all the id's are unique then you could use a join , there a several different types of join but be careful with them as they can generate a lot of work for your database server.

joins - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: please could you accept this an answer, i would be much obliged